# Fragmented network file transfer with 256KB bursts

Tags: windows-10, performance, smb

My upload speed suddenly seems to be limited to 355KB/s (which by the way seems to be some magic number, if you Google it, it get's mentioned in many speed related issues)

I first noticed it while uploading a file to a NAS I'm working on. Yesterday it uploaded at about 60/70 MB/s and today I'm stuck at 355KB/s.

This is on my EliteBook 850 G5 running Windows 10.

I have an older Windows 7 laptop which doesn't seem to have the problem.

I don know if it has anything to do with this but you never know:

This morning my Windows 10 told me it wasn't activated.... strange because it has been activated almost 2 years ago. So I went to settings and there it also showd a "not activated" warning. There was an activate button once clicked i got a popup that told me to reboot. I rebooted and windows was activated again.

What i've tried so far that didn't change anything:

- Use other cables
- Connect laptop to NAS directly without any switch
- Use wifi
- Updated network driver
- Uninstall last update
- Reboot
- Tried uloading file via web browser to esxi (just as slow)
- Tries uploading to a share on the win 7 laptop (just as slow)
- Disable autotuning
- Turn off RDC
- Disable Large send offload
- netsh int ip reset
- flush dns
  at 8 oct:
- tried DISM and SFC
- did a in-place upgrade of Win 10

While using wifi, I have exactly the same speed limit so seems to be some sort of general speed limit or something.

I notice that network usage is strange during a large file transfer:

[image: Network spikes during file transfer]

Its like tranfer starts and then drops every 3 seconds or so...

Using filezilla I have the same problem and the progress info shows bursts of excactly 262144 bytes, so 256KB.

I Loaded Ubuntu live. network speed is great so no hardware issue.

Because both wifi and Ethernet have the same problem i suspect its not a setting of the network adaptor but a more global setting that got messed up.

Facts:

- I'm testing uploads on a local Gb network
- Other conputers dont have the problem.
- problem only with uploads.
- destination doesn't matter, no matter where I upload to, the upload freezes every few seconds.
- both wired and wireless have the same problem with the same speed limit.
- uploading to a pen drive doesn't show the problem
- not a hardware problem because when uploading with ubuntu live disk all works fine.

I'm lost!! Yesterday all was fine, today my max transfer speed seems to be 355KB/s so roughly 3 Mb/s.

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: First try TCP/IP Reset.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt  
Then: ipconfig /flushdns  
Then: restart the computer  .   Then, if that fails, try a USB LAN card and see if that performs better.

Comment: Hi John Thanks for taking the time to help! I have tried you suggestions (I don't have a usb ethernet adaptor though) without any luck.

Comment: Are you using a pirated version of Windows? I've heard of similar problems before, caused by crypto-mining software or other resource consuming viruses.

Comment: Hi! No, this is a legal, payed for Windows. Not much resources are being consumed as far as i can see. CPU is almost sleeping, and loads of memory available.

Comment: Have you tried to fix the system with DISM and SFC? Inspect your network traffic with WireShark, maybe you get epiphany. If that doesn't bare any fruits, boot up into a Linux live system and check how will those transfers behave, If problem doesn't show up, reinstall Windows.

Comment: Hi Leshy, thaks for helping! I updated my post. I did try DISM and SFC with no result. Wire shark shows me bursted transfer but nothing special. Loaded ubuntu live and speed is fine so no hardware issue. I did an in-place update of Win 10. no luck.

Comment: It is unclear if you are "uploading" to a WAN NAS: does this behavior occur when attempting a file transfer within your LAN? If the NAS is local, have you attempted transfers to a different device?

Comment: Hi Yorik, yes, it happens when uploading to a local nas. My older win 7 latop doesn't have the problem. I also made a share on the win 7 laptop and tried to upload from win 10 to the win7 share, same problem. So no matter where you upload to, the transfer pauses every few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last!
I found the solution, or at least some steps that worked in my case.

**First:**

- Open Task Manager.
- Click File > Run new task.
- Copy & paste [gpedit.msc] into the box, tick the box before Create this task with administrative privileges and click OK.
- Under Computer Configuration, double-click on Administrative Templates > Network > QoS Packet Scheduler. Then double-click on Limit reservable bandwidth.
- Click the Enabled option and set Bandwidth limit (%) value to 0. Then click Apply > OK.

I found these steps at: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/easy-fix-windows-10-slow-internet/

After this my upload speed was up to ~10MBps but not the ~100MBps I was used to have.

Then I remembered having fiddled with all kinds of network settings like Disable autotuning, Turn off RDC, Disable Large send offload.

**Second:**
I did another Network Reset.
Settings > network & internet > Status > Network Reset

This will take a few minutes, let it reboot by itself, don't force a reboot (I forced a reboot earlier because i didn't want to wait 5 mins but had to restore my windows after that)

So now all settings are back to default, autotuning is on RDC is on, large send offload is on.

Hope this helps others with the same problem!
Thanks for your help all!

Comment: I tried all that but nothing helps in my case. The strange thing is that I only get this slow speed between a certain 2 computers.